# onTouch always shows Reaction to second event

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event, ontouchlistener

in my App I have a Custom View in an Activity.
To detect touch events I have the method onTouchEvent() in both of them.

Custom View: The onTouchEvent()-method basically just marks the object which is touched.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchedXY[0] = event.getX();
            touchedXY[1] = event.getY();
            mMatrix.mapPoints(touchedXY);                  // this is just for
            event.setLocation(touchedXY[0], touchedXY[1]); // rotation purposes
            for(int i = 0; i < mPoints[i]; i++){
                    mPoints[i].isSelected(setIsSelected(touchedXY)); //using method to
                                                                     //check if point
                                                                     //is selected          
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

Activity: If an Object is touched a LinearLayout should appear at the Bottom of the Activity with the number of touched Points.

```
int key = 0;

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // get masked (not specific to a pointer) action
        int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

        switch (maskedAction) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            List<AddressPoint> selectedPoints = Arrays.asList(mPoints);

            if (key == 0) {
                if (selectedPoints.size() > 0) {
                    key = 1;
                    test.setText(String.valueOf(selectedPoints.size()));
                    popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    test.setText(String.valueOf(selectedPoints.size()));
                }
            } else {
                if (selectedPoints.size() > 0) {
                    test.setText(String.valueOf(selectedPoints.size()));
                } else {
                    key = 0;
                    popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So, it is working but behaves not as desired. The Activity seems only to react to the second touchevent and refreshes every second touchevent.
Like for example:

1. TouchEvent = 4 Points --> Activity shows no popup.
2. TouchEvent = 3 Points --> Activity shows popup with the number "4"
3. TouchEvent = 1 Point --> Activity shows popup with the number "3"
   .
   . and so on
   .

I hope you can help me and I appreciate your help!

Comment: why to override Activity.onTouchEvent?

Comment: In my CustomView I need to mark some points which are touched and in my Activity I want a reaction to the Layout when points are touched. So I have to override it, since it wouldn't listen to changes.

Comment: use a custom listener interface then

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I get the correct data. MY App counts the cliked points correctly, just the LinearLayout shows the information in a weird order.

Comment: when you detect any touch events in your custom view just call some listener,  the same as Button calls OnClickListener.onClick() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to occour because your view is redrawn before the points are saved.

Therefore it might be better to save the number of points in the onTouch onTouchEvent and then invoke another function to set the text accordingly.

Comment: popup is just the Custom LinearLayout. I can't use this Method on my popup Object.

Comment: See the changed answer, hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. I mean, the LinearLayout (popup) shows up with the information, but it's just in a weird order. I don't even "draw" the LinearLayout.

Comment: I think the problem is that you change your data after you shown the points, therefore the order shown is always one step behind.

What are your mPoints and how do you set them?

Comment: The points are in a CustomView and outside the LinearLayout popup. mPoints are just Objects with the x- and y-coordinates of the points.

Comment: And what is test (especally what is the type of test) and at which point is it redrawn

Comment: test is a TextView with the information how much points were selected. Only the points get redrawn when they get touched (they switch the color). So I only redraw the CustomView.

Comment: Can you make sure that the onTouchEvent of your customview is called before onTouch, (e.g. use Log.d() to print out the calls and the number of touch points)

Comment: I just tested it. Now I'm even more confused. The onTouch reacts first in my Activity and after that in my View. So maybe the touch of the points aren't saved when I want to display them... can I change the order of the onTouchEvents?

Comment: It might be better to just use the onTouchEvent function to save the points, and then invoke another function which sets the text accordingly.

Comment: I'll try this and give you a response after that. Thanks so far!

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!! :) You might edit your Answer, so everyone with the same problem can see it without reading all comments =)